# Application Insights HTTP request perfromance data is too unreliable

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, profiler, azure-application-insights

I'm now trying to figure out some performance issues with the application I'm currently working on and I had high hopes for Application Insights (which is a paid service within Azure) to provide some reliable data, but this here is one example of what I get for the number of requests to the same URL within the same interval:
1. Visual Studio - 4300 (built-in AppInsights integration)[image]

2. AppInsights blade within Azure portal - 0:
   [image]
3. AppInsights Analytics - 740:

[image]

Also there is a thing called Application Insights profiler, which shows request execution time equal to say 500ms, but when you go to see stacktraces it becomes 97s!:
[image]
Which result in nice performance tips like this one:
[image]

Can anyone explain how to read this data or maybe point out that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: For #2 - can you please run "requests | project name, operation_Name | take 10" and paste it here? Which OS, AI SDK, version do you use?

Comment: Differences also might come from sampling. Can you run "requests
| summarize max(itemCount)"? The right way to count requests is to take itemCount into account: "requests
| summarize sum(itemCount)"

Comment: @ZakiMa for #2 actually I think I found an explanation, looks like Application Insights decides to name some operations using the route and action name from my C# configs - `routes.MapRoute(...);` rather than URL (for a lot of others it's still URL)

Comment: Developer on Application Insights Profiler here: For #3, please contact us at serviceprofilerhelp@microsoft.com and we'll try and help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `name` field (of request, dependency) is calculated by various code in the various sdks to come up with "nicer" names than just a URL would have. so grouping / counting by `url` and vs by `name` will give you different results.

and as zaki pointed out, any kind of sampling, either client or server, will set `itemCount` on those rows, so you need to use `sum(itemCount)` in any queries you do in analytics to make sure you get the same counts as the views in the portal or in VS

in the VS screenshot, you can see where that top request has a (5) by it that indicates this one row in the database represents 5 requests.

as for question #3, you might want to split it into a separate question, as it isn't really directly related to the first or second, and different people would be able to answer that.